# Using RNGCryptoServiceProvider method to generate Integer between 4 digit to 6 digit

Tags: asp.net, cryptography

Sir,

I have used `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` method to generate integer between the range of 4 digit and 6 digit. Error showed me as `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex` on line `int rnum = r.Next(BitConverter.ToInt32(rno, 100000));`.

Below is code that I am using :

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rg = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
                                byte[] rno = new byte[6];
                                rg.GetBytes(rno);
                                Random r = new Random();
                                int rnum = r.Next(BitConverter.ToInt32(rno, 100000));
```

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

using (RandomNumberGenerator rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
{
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        rng.GetBytes(bytes);
        int val = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        i++;

        // Since 1 million is only 20 bits, just clear all the high bits.
        val &= 0x000FFFFF;

        if (val >= 1000 && val < 1000000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val);
            Console.WriteLine($"Produced on iteration {i}");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In 100 runs it twice required a second iteration to produce numbers within range.

Your particular exception comes from asking BitConverter to read 4 bytes starting at byte 100,000 in your 8 byte array.

In general, one does not want to cross the streams with System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator types and System.Random.